# using curl with trusted timestampgin

Tags: curl

I would like to use the curl library, to get the trusted timestamp of a message.
The command I use is the following:

```
curl --data-binary @inputfile http://url_to_test_tsa --header "Content-type: application/timestamp-request"
```

The problem is, that whatever tsa (timestamping authority) I use, I always get back a server error.
The content of @inputfile is a 40 character length sha1 or md5 hash.

What might be the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the man page: **This posts data exactly as specified with no extra processing whatsoever**

So if you use that option, you need to do the processing yourself.

Comment: What kind of processing do you reffer to? What else do I need?

Comment: I suggest you read up on how to format a HTTP POST request correctly.

Answer (score 0):

basing on [this](https://unmitigatedrisk.com/?p=395) original post and making a few correction, I ended up with the following simplified script to get a somewhat valid reply from a Timestamping Authority (given that I've created `example.txt` file with some gibberish):

```
openssl ts -query -data example.txt -cert -sha256 -out request.tsq
curl -H "Content-Type:application/timestamp-query" --data-binary @request.tsq http://demo.sk.ee/tsa --output response.tsr
```

note that some timestamping services behave differently - e.g. the one I used as an example above doesn't like a timestamping request created using SHA-1 algorithm for the hash (i.e. the output of above openssl command without `-sha256` parameter). Also it seems that the header supplied above is not mandatory, i.e. both services I tried replied with valid response when I didn't use the header at all. Here's `openssl ts` [man page](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/openssl-ts.html).